# How much memory is really used by a vector to which objects are added and then removed?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector to which I keep adding objects (thousands). Once I am done with the objects, I remove them from the vector.

So, if I added a 1000 objects to my vector, and then removed 900 how much memory is my vector really using ? Is it the total amount of memory ever reserved ?

EDIT: How does one reclaim memory, so that the amount of memory used is only for the number of objects actually stored in the vector ?

EDIT: I understand that removing items does not reduce capacity, and adding items in future won't require reallocating memory as long as I am within capacity. But in my scenario, I know after a certain point in my app lifecycle, that I will not be adding to this vector, and so it makes sense to try to reclaim the memory.

Comment: It would still be using the memory of 1000 objects ad vector would store the elements in contiguous memory.

Comment: Consider moving the elements you want to keep to a new vector instead of removing the ones you don't want. It may be faster, since less elements need to be shuffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing elements from a vector, it's capacity (the amount of elements that may fit into it, not the same as it's size) does not necessarily changes. So it's possible that it remains 1000 after removing 100 elements.

Comment: So how does one reclaim the memory reserved ?

Comment: You can call `vector::shrink_to_fit()` to resize the vector to the required size. However as far as I read from the documentation this is only a request and not binding for the implementation.

Comment: If you don't reclaim the memory, then later if you add more items, your vector doesn't need to expand and copy it's full content to a bigger chunk of memory. Also, if you have a vector with size of 1000 doesn't mean it's capacity is 1000 too.

Comment: Removing elements never reduces the capacity.

Comment: At hansmaad. Can you explain the swap trick ? The other answer shows what to do, but I would like to understand what happens to the old vector and the new one.

Comment: @John: The large capacity follows the swap, so the temporary vector which goes out scope has the original large capacity and the remaining vector has the capacity of the newly created vector.

Comment: So when the temporary vector goes out of scope the memory is reclaimed ?